# Fetch and display JSON data correctly without "undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, json

This code is able to fetch and display JSON data but it also shows "undefined" after showing numbers, i want it to show only numbers/prices and not show "undefined" at all. thanks.

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">

<head>
  <title> </title>
</head>
</head>
<style>
  body {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 10;
  }
</style>

<body>


  <div id="output">

  </div>


  <script>
    const pricesWs = new WebSocket('wss://ws.coincap.io/prices?assets=ALL')

    pricesWs.onmessage = function(msg) {
      console.log(msg.data);

      var obj = JSON.parse(msg.data);

      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = '<ol style="font-size:17px;font-family:Arial">' +
        '<li>Bitcoin &emsp;<b>-BTC-</b>' + obj.bitcoin + '</li><br><br>' +
        '<li>Ethereum &emsp;<b>-BTC-</b>' + obj.ethereum + '</li><br><br>' +
        '<li>Litecoin &emsp;<b>-BTC-</b>' + obj.litecoin + '</li><br><br>' +
        '</ol>';


    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because if you inspect the websocket JSON objects, the keys "litecoin", "ethereum" and "bitcoin" are not always present.

If you check these two lines, no "litecoin" key exists. This a sample case where undefined would be rendered in your page.

> {"bitcoin":"12134.47555858","game":"0.01003290","hive-project":"0.00668094","gamecredits":"0.07752385","bitcoin-cash":"445.18730470","eos":"6.37440917","ethereum":"322.95792616","ontology":"1.56287491"}
>   {"shinechain":"0.00267763","roulettetoken":"0.00800351","bitcoin":"12134.44826914","ttc-protocol":"0.07762756","libra-credit":"0.05395170","tron":"0.03498547","bitcoin-cash":"445.18695648","ethereum":"322.95758114"}

A simple way of overcoming this is checking if they're present in the JSON object and update dedicated variables that hold the last known values.

```
const pricesWs = new WebSocket('wss://ws.coincap.io/prices?assets=ALL')
var litecoin = 0
var bitcoin = 0
var ethereum = 0

pricesWs.onmessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg.data);

    var obj = JSON.parse(msg.data);

    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('litecoin')) {
        litecoin = obj.litecoin
    }
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('ethereum')) {
        ethereum = obj.ethereum
    }
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('bitcoin')) {
        bitcoin = obj.bitcoin
    }

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = '<ol style="font-size:17px;font-family:Arial">' +
        '<li>Bitcoin &emsp;<b>-BTC-</b>' + bitcoin + '</li><br><br>' +
        '<li>Ethereum &emsp;<b>-BTC-</b>' + ethereum + '</li><br><br>' +
        '<li>Litecoin &emsp;<b>-BTC-</b>' + litecoin + '</li><br><br>' +
        '</ol>';


};
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't know there's an option to accept response :-) .. if you dont mind i have another problem,  i want to make use of this API from https://newsapi.org/docs/get-started         var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?' +
          'q=Bitcoin&' +
          'from=2019-06-30&' +
          'sortBy=popularity&' +
          'apiKey=127585aa80454ec1b4592edaf30fe366';

var req = new Request(url);

fetch(req)
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.json());
    })

Comment: You should create a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">

<head>
  <title> </title>
</head>
</head>
<style>
  body {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 10;
  }
</style>

<body>


  <div id="output">

  </div>


  <script>
    const pricesWs = new WebSocket('wss://ws.coincap.io/prices?assets=ALL')

    pricesWs.onmessage = function(msg) {
      // console.log(msg.data);

      var obj = JSON.parse(msg.data);

      var bitcoinLiHtml = '';
      if (obj.bitcoin) {
        bitcoinLiHtml = '<li>Bitcoin &emsp;<b>-BTC-</b>' + obj.bitcoin + '</li><br><br>';
      }

      var ethereumLiHtml = '';
      if (obj.ethereum) {
      ethereumLiHtml = '<li>Ethereum &emsp;<b>-BTC-</b>' + obj.ethereum + '</li><br><br>';
      }

      var litecoinLiHtml = '';
      if (obj.litecoin) {
      litecoinLiHtml = '<li>Litecoin &emsp;<b>-BTC-</b>' + obj.litecoin + '</li><br><br>';
      }

      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = '<ol style="font-size:17px;font-family:Arial">' +
        bitcoinLiHtml + ethereumLiHtml + litecoinLiHtml +
        '</ol>';
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```